# How i ask git commands in IntelliJ terminal?

Tags: git, shell, intellij-idea, terminal, command

I just installed IntelliJ, I can use mvn command on the terminal.

But how to use git commands ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Git client installed on your system and it's available in `PATH` environment, it will work automatically in IntelliJ IDEA Terminal.

Comment: You mean this one ? "C:\Program Files\Git\bin"

Comment: Yes, if you have `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` in `PATH`, it will work.